# Creating contour plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I am trying to replicate findings that were in a paper.  The segment of my code that I use to generate the figure is shown below:

```
    xd = linspace(-2.5,2.5,199); % Build the axes in physical dimensions
    yd = linspace(0,4.92,400);
    [xdg, ydg] = meshgrid(yd, xd);
    mesh(xd,yd,sardb)
    colorbar('southoutside')
    colormap(jet)
    xlabel('(cm)'); % x-axis label
    set(gca,'fontsize',12)
    set (gca,'FontName','times new roman') 
    view([90 90])
    caxis([-15 0])
```

In essence the result I'm displaying is a top view of a mesh.  But I need to replicate the contour lines in the paper.  I've tried all of matlab's contour functions but couldn't get the contour lines the author got in the paper.

My result:

[image: My result]

Paper's result:

[image: Paper's result]

Answer (score 0):

Have you used MATLAB command `contour`? For example

```
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);
figure
contour(X,Y,Z)
```